# How can I confirm a skunk inhabitation, and then persuade the stinky squatter to vacate?

Tags: pest-control

I'm fairly sure a skunk has taken up residence under my deck. I'm concerned that my dogs may be sprayed, or worse contract a disease and/or parasites from the animal.

Our area is loaded with skunks, and I recently noticed a hole dug out leading under our low deck.  I often smell a skunky aroma in the evening and at night, especially in the vicinity of the deck.  I'm not positive it's a skunk den, and I'm also not sure how to confirm either way.

Once I've determined it's a skunk den (or not), I'd like to persuade the animal to leave. I now live within city limits, so my typical shotgun remedy is out of the question (neighbors and local law enforcement don't like late night shotgun blasts, or maybe any shotgun blasts). Since we live in a politically correct world, and this is a PC site, solutions should be humane.

Comment: Ammonia near the den should drive them away. The park center near me uses that when they get to close to the buildings.

Comment: Are the skunks gone now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using fox urine in the vicinity to repel the skunks. You can buy it in the hunting section of sporting goods stores. As far as determining if there is a skunk there or not, it could be trick. A motion sensor trail camera would definitely work, but is probably not worth the investment if you don't already own one. To avoid future visits from skunks be sure to keep garbage secure, and avoid compost being out in the open.

The [humane society](http://www.humanesociety.org/) website has a nice section on [skunk problems](http://www.humanesociety.org/animals/skunks/tips/solving_problems_skunks.html) also.

They will not suggest fox urine because the methods of harvesting it don't align with their views, but they mention using kitty litter, which seems like a reasonable option if you have any at your disposal.

Comment: Can you site any credible sources that confirm using fox urine as a repellent?

Comment: Unconfirmed personally, but it seems to be a common tactic. While I find no scientific studies on skunk repellent, reviews on basspro.com seem to suggest that it works for some: 

http://www.basspro.com/Wildlife-Research-Center-Red-Fox-Urine-Hunters-Masking-Scent/product/101548/
"The Red Fox Urine convinced the skunk, who had taken up residence under my front porch, to move elsewhere. Mission accomplished!"